# php shell_exec command doesn't act like bash / returns an error

Tags: php, bash, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

This is my code:

```
$url = escapeshellarg("http://www.mysite.com");
$command = shell_exec("xvfb-run -a -s '-screen 0 640x480x16' wkhtmltopdf --dpi 300  --page-size A4 $url /srv/www/mysite/public_html/tmp_pdf.pdf");
$str = file_get_contents("/srv/www/mysite/public_html/tmp_pdf.pdf");
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($str));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="pdf.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');
die($str);
```

In my bash shell (using Debian) the command

> shell_exec("xvfb-run -a -s '-screen 0 640x480x16' wkhtmltopdf --dpi
>   300  --page-size A4 html://www.mysite.com /srv/www/mysite/public_html/tmp_pdf.pdf

works and it generates a pdf in the desired location but when i excecute the command in php nothing gets created and i'm returned to a null pdf file (because it doesn't exist).
Can someone help me figure what is wrong?

Comment: I hope the html:// protocol exists, else you may want to try http:// .. Further more, to be sure there are no characters in the URL which are interpretted otherwise in shell_exec/bash, use escapeshellarg() on the url http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php before passing it as a param. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Apache server doesn't have write access to the folder i've tried to write the pdf into (which is /srv/www/mysite/public_html/ in my example).

So i simply changed the folder location to /tmp (where everyone has write permissions) and now it works. The corrected code is:

```
$url = escapeshellarg("http://www.mysite.com");
$command = shell_exec("xvfb-run -a -s '-screen 0 640x480x16' wkhtmltopdf --dpi 300  --page-size A4 $url /tmp/tmp_pdf.pdf");
$str = file_get_contents("/tmp/tmp_pdf.pdf");
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($str));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="pdf.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');
die($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your tool there, so take this with a metric ton of salt.

If you have the url and the tool downloads the url itself, there might be some network permissions blocking. If you can download the url on your own and give this tool simply the content (or from a temp file) that might eliminate that possibility.

Also check permissions on the folder you try to write into there.

Since you say Debian, execute the following:

```
which xvfb-run
```

This will give you the FULL path to the executable, which I would use in that call for shell_exec.

As for streaming the file out, I would use readfile.

```
$filePath = "/srv/www/mysite/public_html/tmp_pdf.pdf";

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="pdf.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');

readfile($filePath);
exit();
```

The advantage is that the entire file does not need to be read into memory for this.